# How to compare multiple elements of a char array to one hex value?

Tags: c++

Recently I have been working on my own Java 8 Bytecode decompiler. I'm having a problem with checking the magic of a class file in a nice way.

Let's say I have a unsigned char array and the elements 0 to 3 are the magic, for total of 4-bytes of magic.

The following doesn't look like a very appealing way to write the magic check:

```
if ((data[0] != 0xCA) && (data[1] != 0xFE) && (data[2] != 0xBA) && (data[3] != 0xBE))
{
...
}
```

Would it be possible to write in a shorter manner? Like:

```
if (data[0 to 4] != 0xCAFEBABE)
{
...
}
```

Code is available [here](https://github.com/tambry/Polaron), the relevant part being located [here](https://github.com/tambry/Polaron/blob/master/Polaron/Polaron/Loader.cpp#L61-#L67).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
if (reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(data)[0] != 0xCAFEBABE)
{
...
}
```

Depending on the endianes of your machine, you'll have to compare to `0xCAFEBABE` or `0xBEBAFECA`.

Comment: static_cast doesn't work, but reinterpret_cast does.

Comment: @tambre, you are correct. I have edited my solution accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it.

1.One option is to use `uint32_t *`.

```
 uint32_t *val_4BytePtr = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(data);

 if (*val_4BytePtr == 0x...)
```

The downside of this option is that it may be not portable since the result which will be in `*val_4BytePtr` will depend on the "endian" policy (big endian/little endian).

2.Secont option is to combine such `uint32_t`

```
uint32_t val_4Byte = (static_cast<uint32_t>(data[3]) << 24) | 
                     (static_cast<uint32_t>(data[2]) << 16) | 
                     (static_cast<uint32_t>(data[1]) << 8) | data[0];

if (val_4Byte == 0x...)
```

In this case the data stored in `val_4Byte` will always have the same format.

Answer (score 0):

Try `memcmp`

> Compares the first num bytes of the block of memory pointed by ptr1 to
>   the first num bytes pointed by ptr2, returning zero if they all match
>   or a value different from zero representing which is greater if they
>   do not.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/